# How to set Inf as limits for rectangles made with rect in R?

Tags: r, plot, rectangles

I want to add rectangles to a plot that possibly end outside the bounds of the plot, but it seems that `rect` does not support `Inf` in its arguments

```
plot(NA, xlim = c(0, 10), ylim = c(0, 10))
rect(xleft = 2, ybottom = 0, xright = 3, ytop = Inf, col = "red")
```

Even if I have the workaround

```
ylim <- c(0, 10)
plot(NA, xlim = c(0, 10), ylim = ylim)
tmp <- ylim[2] + dist(ylim) 
#+ dist(ylim) is necessary as plot does not strictly end at ylim (resp. xlim)
rect(xleft = 2, ybottom = 0, xright = 3, ytop = tmp, col = "red")
```

I'm asking this questions, because firstly I guess that there is some build in option in `R` to allow `+-Inf` in `rect` which would make the code cleaner and secondly I have to run the workaround also for `xleft`, `ybottom` and `xright` , making it unpleasant.

Comment: Just pick a Really Big Number, like `rbn = .Machine$integer.max`

Comment: @Gregor good idea, but it doesn't work in general. See for example rect `(xleft = 2, ybottom = 0 - 1e6, xright = 3, ytop = 1, col = "red");
rect(xleft = 2, ybottom = 0 - 1e8, xright = 3, ytop = 1, col = "blue")` the blue rectangle goes up!